# How does automatic login work?

Tags: 11.04, login, gdm

I found that one my user login for user (hadoop) automatically gets logged in after boot process. I wanted to know where exactly in the boot process it does.

Answer (score 3):

In GDM. `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

```
[daemon]    
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=hadoop
```

You can just edit that manually.